# Why the entire code of the imported class from the file is getting executed in the caller file?

Tags: python, class, python-import

class being called is Testing from prg.py file

```
class Testing:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def print_something():
        print("Class name: " + str(__class__))
arr = [2, 3, 9]


def adding(arr):
    i = len(arr) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        arr[i] += 1
        if arr[i] == 10:
            arr[i] = 0
            i -= 1
        else:
            break
    if i == -1:
        arr.insert(0, 1)
    return arr


print(adding(arr))

count = 1


def doThis():
    global count  # global keyword will now make the count variable as global
    for i in (1, 2, 3):
        count += 1


doThis()
print(count)

for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
else:
    print("Here")
```

The caller file is test.py, the code of which is as follows

```
from prg import Testing

t = Testing("t2")
t.print_something()
```

Output when executing test.py is as follows

```
[2, 4, 0]
4
0
1
2
3
4
Class name: <class 'prg.Testing'>
```

What do I need to do in order to make sure that only the code under Testing class executes and not of entire prg.py file?

Comment: You can't do that. Importing a file always executes all the code in the file, since it has no way of knowing which parts are needed by the names that are being imported.

Comment: If you don't want it to be executed, don't put it into the top-level code, put it in functions.

Comment: So I need to include only the 'Testing' class related code inside prg.py file and remove everything else?

Comment: Or put "everything else" in a function, which you can execute if you want.

Comment: You have `print(adding(arr))` at top level which is causing that function to run. Put that and anything else inside another function or `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Carcigenicate. As per your comments I moved the remaining code inside of a function and now only the 'Testing' class code executed when invoked from test.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stuff like `print(adding(arr))` at top level. That's why.

Popular way to solve the issue is to format your code like this:

```
class Testing:
    pass

# Other classes and functions 

def main():
   # Whatever you need to test this particular script goes here

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Now if you use

```
from prg import Testing
```

you wont be printing anything because now `__name__` is `prg` when python tries to import the class `Testing`

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Carcigenicate. As per your comments, I moved the remaining code to a seperate function in the file and now only 'Testing' class code executes when called.